# How to make form body in axios react native

Tags: react-native, image, axios

I want to upload image in react native, so I use react native image picker. In my postman the api can upload image, but in mycode nothing update. in below example consume api in postman

[image]

in my code like this:

```
const handlePickImage = () => {
    launchImageLibrary(
      {
        mediaType: 'photo',
        quality: 0.5,
      },
      (response) => {
        if (response.didCancel) {
          console.log('User cancelled image picker');
        } else if (response.error) {
          console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
        } else if (response.customButton) {
          console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
        } else {
          const { uri, type, fileName } = response?.assets?.[0];
          console.log(response?.assets);
          if (uri) {
            setSelectedImage({
              name: formik.values.companyName.replace(/\s/g, '-'),
              uri,
              type,
              fileName,
            });
            setPreviewImage(uri);
          } else {
            console.log('Fail to pick image!');
          }
        }
      },
    );
  };
```

This is my logic for submit data

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', selectedImage?.fileName);

await handleSubmit(formData);

const handleSubmit = async (input) => {
    try {
      const result = await axios.patch(`${BASE_URL}/company/profile`, input, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Gosnix ${DataLoginReducers?.token}` },
      });

      if (result.status == 200 || result.status === 'success' || result.status == 201) {
        formik.resetForm();
        setModalActive({ status: false });
        setErrorMessage('');
        navigation.goBack();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setModalActive({ status: true, type: 'error' });
      setErrorMessage(translations['please.try.again']);
    }
  };
```

anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

in your headers add `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"`. When sending formdata, you need to tell the backend what type of data to expect so in this case it would be multipart/form-data.